# Google Analytics Events for li items

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-handling, html-lists, href

I'm trying to add Google Analytics click tracking events to li list items (active thumbnails) used in a responsive grid application, and can't get it working.  I've researched here and in the Google developer forums without success.  I'm sure there is something simple I'm doing wrong.  I have the latest GA script code installed (page view analytics are working fine).  Here is a code sample:

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="link" data-url="http://www.dianagabaldon.com/books/outlander-series/" data-target="_self" >
    <a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'GridLinks', 'Click', 'Outlander Clicks 1']);"></a></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-path="outlander_files/thumbnails/outlanderbookseries1.png" ></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-text >
        <p class="largeLabel" >Diana Gabaldon -  Outlander Series</p></li>
</ul>
```

Hope you can help.  Feel free to suggest a better way of doing it.

Update:  I'm still digging, and the GA code has been updated for Universal Analytics and looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="link" data-url="http://www.dianagabaldon.com/books/outlander-series/" data-target="_self" >
       <a href="#" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'thumbnail', 'click', 'Outlander Clicks 1');"></a></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-path="outlander_files/thumbnails/outlanderbookseries1.png" ></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-text >
        <p class="largeLabel" >Diana Gabaldon -  Outlander Series</p></li>
</ul>
```

Update 2: I tried opening the outbound link target in a new page to see if a lack of callBack might be the problem.  No success.  Following are two views of the code, one with the  contained inside the li with the outbound link, the other in a separate li with the same parent ul.  Neither works.  Does anyone know which syntax is correct?  Thx.

Example 1: With href in it's own li:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'thumbnail', 'click', 'Outlander Clicks 1');"></a></li>
    <li data-type="link" data-url="http://www.dianagabaldon.com/books/outlander-series/" data-target="_blank" ></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-path="outlander_files/thumbnails/outlanderbookseries1.png" ></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-text >
        <p class="largeLabel" >Diana Gabaldon -  Outlander Series</p></li>
</ul>
```

Example 2: With href inside outbound link li:

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="link" data-url="http://www.starz.com/outlandercommunity/home.html" data-target="_blank" >
        <a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'thumbnail', 'click', 'Outlander Clicks 2');"></a></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-path="outlander_files/thumbnails/community1.png" ></li>
    <li data-thumbnail-text >
        <p class="largeLabel" >Starz:  Outlander Community</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using for the event tracking uses the classic GA syntax (_gaq.push), but if you are using Universal Analytics (assuming that is what you mean by using the "latest GA script code"), the syntax needs to be updated:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'GridLinks', 'Click', 'Outlander Clicks 1');"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I discovered that myself and updated it – still no joy.  I have page-level events pushing no problem, so I feel something must be wrong with how I'm using the li syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Responsive Grid, but the likely explanation is that the call to `ga` only adds the event to a queue for asynchronous processing, and that the event is lost because the current document is immediately replaced afterwards (stopping the JavaScript execution for the current page). You would need to use a hit callback as described in the [Google Analytics help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920), but I'm not sure how this would be integrated with Responsive Grid. Also note that there are a couple of [other pitfalls](http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/24/outbound-link-tracking.html) you need to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought you might have solved it because the async problem you described would explain why page load is successfully pushing an event, but outbound link triggers are not.  I changed the link target to _blank so that the links open in a new page, leaving the page in question running, and it didn't help.  No joy yet.

Comment: Did you check if the code in the onClick attribute is executed at all?

Comment: It isn't being executed.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the syntax.  Each ul represents an active thumbnail in a js-based responsive grid.  When a thumbnail is clicked, it sends the user to a new page.  I need to register and track each thumbnail click.  Here is a link to an example page:  http://addozones.com/Outlander/outlander.html

Comment: In that case the question is not directly related to Google Analytics. You should probably rewrite it to increase the chance of getting attention from people familiar with Responsive Grid.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that too.  To be clear, it is only the ga event push that is not running.  I'm trying to determine if it's because I'm embedding it in the ul/li incorrectly.